# Что не так с кодом на Python 3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, информатика

Есть задача на Python 3 с условием:

> Дана цепочка, состоящая из синих (B) и красных (R) точек. Нужно
> удалить наименьшее одинаковое количество синих и красных точек так,
> чтобы сначала шли только синие, а потом – только красные.
>
> Входные данные
>
> Входная строка содержит только символы 'B' и 'R' без пробелов.
>
> Выходные данные
>
> Нужно вывести полученную цепочку, в которой сначала идут только синие
> точки, а потом – только красные. Во второй строке нужно вывести
> количество удалённых (синих и красных) точек.

и примерами:

> ```
> Примеры
> Ввод
> BBBRBBRBRBRRRRRR
> Вывод
> BBBBBRRRRRRR
> 4
> ```

Пытаюсь пол часа решить, использую разные варианты, но всё равно не получается.
Вот последний вариант кода:

```
n = input()
s = ''
count = 0
for g in range(0, len(n)):
    if g == len(n) - 1:
       break
    if n[g] == 'B' and n[g + 1] == 'B':
       s += 'B'
       continue
    elif n[g] == 'B' and n[g + 1] == 'R':
        if count == 0:
            s += 'B'
        else:
            s += 'R'
        continue
    elif n[g] == 'R' and n[g + 1] == 'B':
        s += 'R'
        count += 1
        continue
    elif n[g] == 'R' and n[g + 1] == 'R':
        continue
print(s)
print(count)
```

Что я делаю не так? В чём и где ошибки? Подскажите, пожалуйста, как правильно решить задачу и что использовать?!

Comment: А какой алгоритм Вы заложили в решение-то? По идее - просто проверяем, соответствует ли строка условию, если нет, удаляем самую первую красную и самую последнюю синюю и повторяем. Напишите функции поиска позиций самой первой красной и самой последней синей точек - будет удобнее.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Это конечно не лучший вариант, но все же рабочий

```
def ed(a):
    if a:
        b = a.split('R')
        r = a.split('B')
        sorted_b = [y for y in b if y]
        sorted_a = [y for y in r if y]
        sorted_b.sort()
        sorted_a.sort()
        count_b = sorted_b.count(sorted_b[0])
        count_a = sorted_a.count(sorted_a[0])
        cb = min(map(len, sorted_b))
        bb = ''.join(list(filter(lambda x: len(x) > cb, sorted_b)))
        cr = min(map(len, sorted_a))
        rr = ''.join(list(filter(lambda x: len(x) > cr, sorted_a)))
        res = bb.count('B') * "B" + rr.count("R") * "R"
        return f'{res} {count_a + count_b}'

print(ed("BBBRBBRBRBRRRRRR"))
```

Вывод будет:

```
BBBBBRRRRRR 5
```

Answer (score 1):

данное решение подойдет сугубо для данного ввода строки, выглядит так:

```
s = "BBBRBBRBRBRRRRRR"
bb = s[:s.find('RR')]
rr = s[s.find('RR'):]
bb = bb.replace('R', '')
print(bb + rr, s.count('BR'))
```

1-делим на две части строку, до момента, где начинаются RR,

2-потом в первой заменяем R на пуcтое значение, т.е. удаляем.

3-в выводе "склеиваем" назад в строку, подсчитываем буквосочетание BR

Comment: узковато ......